# Are deep-space EVAs part of the Artemis plan?

Tags: eva, artemis-program

During [Apollos 15, 16, and 17](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extravehicular_activity#Apollo_lunar_EVA), the first deep-space EVAs were performed to retrieve film canisters from the exterior of the vehicle while in translunar space on the way home, producing what is, without a doubt, one of the most spectacular selfies of history so far.

[image]

No further deep-space EVAs have been performed since.

Is there any reason to do more during Artemis perhaps near LOP-G or outside of Orion? Is it even possible with the architecture Artemis will use?